# How to assign a global variable in Chromium?

Tags: c++, windows, chromium, cc

My goal is to pass a launch parameter to the startup method (WinMain), which will declare the contents of this parameter a global variable. Example `chromium.exe --my-parameter parameter-data`. Now, let's imagine I took this input data and assigned it to a variable string called **myParameter**. How do I make this variable accessible to the rest of the .cc files? The reason I need this is to differentiate between different instances of the browser (running simultaneously) inside the code, as the launch parameter will be a unique identifier for that session.

Comment: Every instance of a process already has a unique PID (process ID), which is accessible from anywhere in the process by calling `GetCurrentProcessId `. You should explain why you need *another* unique identifier.

Comment: So are you trying to differentiate instances of browser processes or render processes?

Comment: @dxiv Thank you for your answer, that works too.

Comment: @dxiv Just got the time to test, the PID from GetCurrentProcessId() keeps changing, even while the window is open. Is that normal?

Comment: @artemixer The PID does not change during the lifetime of a process. If you are seeing different PIDs then you are looking at different processes.

Comment: @dxiv Yes, after some testing I realised that I was using GetCurrentProcessId() inside the reader, which is the same for all browser instances, no matter what instance of the browser called it. Is there any way to pass additional parameters or variables to the reader, in this case, the PID specific to that instance of the browser?